# Integrating BackgroundService to my app?

Tags: android, email

I'm doing one application like raising email intent by time using `AlarmManager`. In this app, the Email intent raising by time perfectly. If we set one time for raising Email intent, it'll work.

If we restart the device, before the time of event is reached. Then, the app should be work. But, it does not work.

What am missing? What they need to raise this after restarting the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need using `BroadcastReceiver` with action `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />` in manifest file. Then you need start service from it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just done this by `BroadcastReceiver` and, just check the time also there.

Answer (score 2):

I Think you should you SharedPreferences to save your state.
Look into following code and do some search regarding SharedPreferences.
its easy to implement.

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mSettingsTimePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        sharedHour = hourOfDay;
        sharedMinute = minute;

        previousSharedHour = hourOfDay;
        previousSharedMinute = minute;

        try {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            objDate = c.getTime();

            SharedPreferences alarmSettings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = alarmSettings.edit();

            prefEditor.remove(PREFS_NAME);
            prefEditor.commit();

            alarmSettings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            prefEditor = alarmSettings.edit();

            System.out.println("In seting dialog :   "+hourOfDay +" : "+minute);
            prefEditor.putInt("sharedHour", hourOfDay);
            prefEditor.putInt("sharedMinute", minute);
            prefEditor.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```